# Big Query | Error: Not Found: Project <project-id>

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting the below error in Big Query Browser Tool.

Error: Not Found: Project

Have verified that, Big Query API is turned ON and billing also enabled. 
Please let me know the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had found that this error occurred if (when) cookies were disabled in your browser.  Let me know if this resolves this issue.  You may also test via other methods, i.e. API, etc... to make sure that your account is actually enabled - Here's the URL -  [URL to BigQuery API documentation](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/developers_guide)

Answer (score 0):

See [BigQuery error in query operation : Project id not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224485/bigquery-error-in-query-operation-project-id-not-found/14226091#14226091).

It looks like there is an issue with projects that were created via appengine. Let me know if that is the case for your project.