# BigQuery error in query operation : Project id not found

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting a project not found error when trying to run queries with the bq command line tool or the BigQuery browser window.

- I've registered the BigQuery API with the project.  I've also setup billing.
- For bq, I've setup the .bigqueryrc with the numeric project id.
- When I try to query the system response is using the friendly project id so it seems that BigQuery is aware enough to do this mapping of numeric to friendly ids.
- I've used the bq shell to verify that prompt reflects the right project id.
- I can run 'bq ls publicdata:samples' just fine so I'm assuming the authorization really kicks in to query the data.

What's missing or wrong here?

Comment: What is the query that you're running? It is likely the issue is with the table name in the query.

Comment: samples i found online; e.g., bq query 'select count(*) from publicdata:samples.wikipedia'

Comment: Looks like a bug. Filed internally and am investigating.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue recognizing projects created through AppEngine. This is a bug and we're actively working on a fix.

As a workaround, you can use a project created through https://code.google.com/apis/console instead.

Comment: Any word on the workaround for this?  If I create a new project how do I get access to the data in the project I'm targeting?  Won't creating a new project mean I'm working with an empty datastore? Thanks.

Comment: This bug should have been fixed 2 years ago. Can you describe your problem, perhaps with a new question?

Comment: It is the same error message as in the project title.  Am out of town but if you still need a new question let me know and I will get back to you in a few days.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I didn't have App Engine enabled. For me it was solved by authenticating again though gcloud:

```
$ gcloud auth login
```